# Inverting a table (not transposing)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm working with tissue micro-array (TMA) image analysis for a molecular pathology project. TMAs are slides with lots of small images, and after the slide is scanned it needs to be matched up with the map of unique IDs.

Sometimes the slides are rotated, so what I need is a way of flipping an Excel table, but not transposing if that makes any sense.

For example

From:

[image]

to:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally prefer to solve problems without macros, however I couldn't find an easy solution without them now.

Below macro inverts selected matrix and writes it back to the original location or to a new worksheet.

To run the macro:

- Press Alt+F11 to open Visual Basic editor
- paste the code in a module (insert - module)

  - note: after adding a code, you'll need to save your workbook as macro enabled workbook if you want to keep the macro (if you won't need it in the future, than it's also fine to keep as .xlsx)
- keep the option you need (overwrite original data or create new sheet) and delete the other
- select the whole table you need to invert
- go to "view" - "macros" - "view macros" - select the macro (InvertTable) and press run

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub InvertTable()
    Dim originalData As Variant
    Dim nRows As Integer
    Dim nColumns As Integer
    Dim newData As Variant
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer

    originalData = Selection
    nRows = UBound(originalData, 1)
    nColumns = UBound(originalData, 2)
    newData = originalData

    For x = 1 To CInt(nColumns / 2)
        For y = 1 To CInt(nRows / 2)
            newData(y, x) = originalData(nRows - y + 1, nColumns - x + 1)
            newData(nRows - y + 1, nColumns - x + 1) = originalData(y, x)
            newData(y, nColumns - x + 1) = originalData(nRows - y + 1, x)
            newData(nRows - y + 1, x) = originalData(y, nColumns - x + 1)
        Next y
    Next x

    ' --- option 1: overwrite data ---
    Selection = newData
    ' --- end of option 1 ---

    ' --- option 1: insert new sheet ---
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet

    Set newSheet = Selection.Parent.Parent.Worksheets.Add
    newSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(nRows, nColumns)) = newData
    ' --- end of option 1 ---
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with INDEX:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$C$3,((ROWS($A$1:$A$3))+1)-ROWS($G$1:$G1),((COLUMNS($A$1:$C$1))+1)-COLUMNS($G$1:G1))
```

This assumes your table is in the range `$A$1:$C$3`,

You will need to go into my formula and change the ranges to suit your needs.

Change `$A$1:$C$3` to suit the full range of your table.
Change `$A$1:$A$3` to suit the top ROW of your table.
Change `$A$1:$C$1` to suit the first column of your table.

Make sure you have the $ signs in there tho.

[image]

**EDIT for OP**

In Cell `M1` us the below formula:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$L$9,((ROWS($A$1:$A$9))+1)-ROWS($N$1:$N1),((COLUMNS($A$1:$L$1))+1)-COLUMNS($N$1:N1))
```

Drag it across to `X1`, and then down to `X9`, to directly invert your original table.

Comment: Hi PeterH,Thanks for the reply. 

I'm sure I'm doing something silly but I can't get it working. My Data is in the range A1 to L9

Comment: @dougzy see my edit

Answer (score 2):

You may create a helper row with 9 to 1 starting from N2 cell and a helper column with 12 to 1 starting from O1 cell.

Now, put the following formula and drag right and down:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$L$9,$N2,O$1)
```

See the following Picture:

[image]